# Selenium with Xvfb: firefox.NotConnectedException

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I have selenium running on a server and I want it to display the browser on the client.
I have launched xvfb on my server like that:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

Then on my Java code I wrote:

```
    String xPort = System.getProperty("Importal.xvfb.id", ":1");
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/lib/firefox/firefox"));
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", xPort);
    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

But when I launch I have this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 

(process:28971): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'franceservice', ip: '149.202.55.131', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-22-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:397)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 

(process:28971): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'franceservice', ip: '149.202.55.131', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-22-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:221)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:212)
    com.franceservice.controllers.bo.BOResultat.sendById(BOResultat.java:329)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1073)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:28971): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:221)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:212)
    com.franceservice.controllers.bo.BOResultat.sendById(BOResultat.java:329)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1073)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Selenium's version is 2.47.1 and firefox is 33.0.
Selenium is running from a web interface deployed on tomcat.

Comment: I have this same issue, please were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

you need for RANDR extension. try following:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -extension RANDR &
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but the warning still appears and nothing change.